# Cube Combining Facts

Tags: ssas

My goal is to generate a report that has by day: order count, quantity sum, receive sum (we ship our product out and get it back). I have two cubes now: one for the orders and one for the receives. I've created a new cube that includes both dimensions but they are not in sync by date. It's as if there is not a join between the two fact tables by the date. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "both dimensions"?

Comment: I should have said "that includes both measure". In a relational database my query would be based on dimdate and I'd have outer joins or subqueries for my measures for that date. How can I accomplish the same thing in a cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one cube, include both your orders and receives Measure Groups, and one instance of your Date dimension.  In the cube's Dimensions Relationships tab, relate both Measure Groups to the Date dimension using their relevant date keys.